# Кнопки произвольной формы в Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity3d, gui

Как реализовать кнопку произвольной формы?

Имеется Button, имеется текстура с альфа-каналом, имеющая полностью прозрачные области (якобы там ничего и нет. Как никак, графический файл являет собой прямоугольную область). Нужно, чтобы область реагирования на клик у кнопки совпадала с непрозрачной частью наложенной на кнопку текстуры. Если просто натянуть текстуру на кнопку, последняя реагирует на нажатия в любой точке картинки, даже прозрачной.

Встречал [вот такое решение](https://devby.ru/afrokick/2012/10/24/knopki-proizvolnoy-formy-button-shape-v-unity3d.html), датированное далеким 2012-м, но, почему-то, кажется, что должно быть что-то более оптимальное. Во-первых, в плане оптимизации, а во-вторых: данное решение, как я понимаю, имеет явный недостаток — одна кнопка своей прозрачной областью может мешать нажать на другую.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не совсем понятно, что вы в итоге хотите получить: простую кастомную кнопку или также карту делаете, как в приведенном вами примере или еще что-то.

Как бы то ни было, в *Unity* уже имеются разные инструменты для работы с такими текстурами. К примеру, есть у вас текстура со множеством точек перехода? Без проблем. Делаете картинку спрайтом, навешиваете на неё **[Polygon Collider 2D](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/Manual/class-PolygonCollider2D.html)** и делаете скрипт, который реагирует на действия, например, на наведение мыши:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PolygonColliderHover : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    private SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer;

    void OnMouseOver() {
        spriteRenderer.color = Color.red;
    }

    void OnMouseExit() {
        spriteRenderer.color = Color.white;
    }
}
```

Всё. Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видим, картинка имеет коллайдер, по форме "обтекающий" текстуру, при наведении на который что-то происходит.

---

Тоже самое можно делать и с картой. Навешиваем всё тот же **[Polygon Collider 2D](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/Manual/class-PolygonCollider2D.html)** у которого можно добавить **множество** областей, которые имеют  **множеством** кастомных координат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Твори что угодно. Вот пример при наведении на одну из областей карты:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Саму карту можно делать с прозрачным фоном. У спрайта есть **SpriteMode** `Multiple` и `Polygon`, позволяющие отделить те же материки на карте друг от друга.

Comment: Алексей, благодарю! Ответ - в точку, еще и развернуто. Насчет вашего уточнения - интересовал универсальный случай(карта тут взята как единственный найденный пример), т.е. чтобы иметь возможность делать кнопки произвольной формы в GUI. Вы мне эту возможность дали)